# Nginx + node.js single page app, sending /index.html and proxying together

Tags: nginx, http, node.js

I've got a Nginx running, with Node.js on port 3000.

```
    location / {
        root   /path/to/my/site;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @node;
    }

    location @node {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    }
```

this works perfectly, getting node content when the url is not a file. (so this loads socket.io/socket.io.js fine).

Now i want all pages to redirect to my index.html in the root. So when a users refreshes //domain/with/extra/path; i want to ship the root //domain/index.html.

i would need a rewrite for this, but that would destroy my checking for node files. So i need something that only redirects the GET /(url)/ to my root /index.html, not GET files.

Comment: So redirecting all requests with a trailing `/`, is that correct?

Comment: i think that should work, yes!

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your `location /` should cause any request with a trailing slash to load the index page:

```
rewrite ^/.*/$ / last;
```

Or if you want to send their browser a redirect response so their address bar points to the new location, swap `last` for `permanent` (or `redirect` if you'd prefer a 302 over a 301).

Comment: it seems this also catches links with a / in the middle

Comment: @Laurens Are you sure those requests don't have a `/` on the end?  The `/$` makes sure that the final character in the string being matched is a `/`.

Comment: i see now, the file i'm referring to ends with /?t=.. which of course ends with /. Can i check on this too?